# Why is it a bad idea to use event handler method signatures deviating from sender and eventargs?

Tags: c#, event-handling, code-analysis

The code analysis tool in VS 2012 has suggested a few problems with my code. Most are fine, [This one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) (CA1009 Declare event handlers correctly) however I can't understand the reasoning for.

If I don't need any data, just to know that something has occurred, it seems to me that I'm obfuscating my real intentions by using events with unneeded parameters.

For example, say I want to list all customers who match a given criteria. If my repository is updated, I need to recheck the data.

So I create a repository class, then give it a DataChanged event with the following signature:

```
public event Action DataChanged;
```

Then in one of the classes using the repo I can do

```
repository.DataChanged += UpdateMatchingCustomers;

private void UpdateMatchingCustomers() {
    MatchingCustomers = ...
}
```

Why is this a bad idea?

Comment: Because any other programmer that reads your code will think there's something wrong with it.  And can then neither find the flaw nor can find the reason you did it this way.  A distraction.  You are entirely free to ignore the advice.  But it is usually best to treat the guy that takes over your job as a homicidal maniac that knows where you live.

Comment: Does the class have to be public? If not marking it as internal *should* make this go away. (That is if you really don't want to change or suppress this, Hans make a good point).

Comment: I'm not so much wanting to suppress the warning, as know why it is considered best practice. On the MSDN page I linked, it even says "Do not suppress a warning from this rule.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main idea is that somebody might want to use the same event handler method to handle events from multiple sources, and having a matching signature is helpful:

- Enforcing the existence of `sender` makes sure the handler can distinguish between different event sources
- Having all the event data objects derive from `EventArgs` ensures that there's always a proper type to use for the data argument

Additionally, having a base class for event data and enforcing it ensures that classes that extend the event source can send more data with the existing event than the base class, and this makes sure it's possible (granted, this is a bit far-fetched, but I have done this at least once in an actual program).

I also wouldn't be surprised if some of Microsoft's fancy designers (they sure love them designers) broke if an event didn't follow their expected pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue about the EventArgs parameter, there are pros anc cons.

But the sender is a must have, if the same handler is attached to multiple objects then this is how you determine which instance raises the event.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem a bit odd, but this rule makes sense, it would be ideal to declare your event so you do not have to create a new delegate:

```
public event EventHandler<CalculaMontosEventArgs> CantidadesEvent = delegate { };
public class CalculaMontosEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public CalculaMontosEventArgs(decimal total)
    {
        Total = total;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from a permormance Point this design rule makes no sence, to comunicate a value type in an delegate oor Action you Need to generate a refference type, that contains a value type...

ok, for user readability and maintenance this is grait, it adds context and meaning to something like

Public Action MyAction; however, Code comments can do that as well...